# Issue (With Boost?) When Installing Carmel

Tags: c++, boost, installation

I am attempting to install [Carmel](https://github.com/graehl/carmel/blob/master/README), which is causing some issues. I'm running OSX 10.7.5 on my machine, and I think the prerequisite boost installation is causing issues.

I've installed boost, but when trying to install Carmel, get errors like:

```
In file included from ../../graehl/carmel/src/fst.h:4,
                 from ./src/fst.cc:3:
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:8:25: error: fst/compat.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:32:29: error: fst/vector-fst.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../graehl/carmel/src/fst.h:4,
                 from ./src/carmel.cc:33:
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:8:25: error: fst/compat.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:32:29: error: fst/vector-fst.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:36:26: error: fst/minimize.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:37:27: error: fst/rmepsilon.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:38:29: error: fst/determinize.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:39:25: error: fst/connect.h: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:42:27: error: fst/lib/util.cc: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:43:26: error: fst/lib/fst.cc: No such file or directory
../../graehl/carmel/src/config.hpp:44:28: error: fst/lib/flags.cc: No such file or directory
```

Could someone point me in the right direction with these errors. I'm not where to turn here, or where to look.

Thanks!

Comment: seems unrelated to boost based on the error messages you posted. It looks like your include paths are not configured correctly?

Comment: Got it. It turned out to be a whole host of issues. Ended up just reinstalling my OS

Comment: Adam_G - post you own answer and accept it please